# Getting error while performing insert operation in hive 1.0.0 when integrate with tez0.5.2

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

iam using **hive 1.0.0** and **tez 0.5.2.**
when i set **hive.execution.engine** value in hive-site.xml to **tez** select query works well... but in case of **insert** getting error.
the query is :

**insert into table tablename values(intvalue,'string value');**

and the error is :

**FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.Tez Task**

Comment: Please read the part "Inserting data into Hive Tables from queries" in the official document https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't just do "insert" into a hive table. Can you create your table as an `EXTERNAL TABLE` or use `LOAD DATA INPATH`?

Comment: create as an external table